# How to process an inner Exception with ILoggingEvent

Tags: java, spring, exception, logback

I am creating a custom logback appender.
This is my code for throwing an exception with an inner exception intentionally:

```
    public void testRoute() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("First Exception", new Exception("Second Exception", new Exception("Third Exception")));
    }
```

And this is the code of my custom logback appender

```
    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent event) {
        IThrowableProxy throwable = event.getThrowableProxy();
        System.out.println(throwable.getClassName() + ": " + throwable.getMessage());
    }
```

The IThrowableProxy just gives me the "third Exception" exception and I can't get the other exceptions.
With the ILoggingEvent I just get the "first Exception" exception.

How can I get all of the inner exceptions?

Comment: If you get the first exception, wouldn't [`getCause`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause()) (repeat till it returns `null`) give you any nested exception?

Comment: The behavior is exactly like @Robert stated. My problem was that I didn't log the exception correctly and it went through some spring framework related stuff.  Sadly I can't remember exactly what I did wrong, but if one logs the exception like `logger.error("message", exception);` everything should work as expected